# Cucumber duplicate class problem: AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I am having a problem with Cucumber when there is a reference to self in a model callback method.

Code example below.
The error is like:
Person(#26738680) expected, got Person(#29003170) (ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base


  has_one :person_profile    
  accepts_nested_attributes_for : person_profile                             
  after_create :new_person_profile

  private 

  def new_person_profile
    person_profile = PersonProfile.new( 
      ...,
      :person => self  # <--- this causes the error in cucumber
    ) 
    self.person_profile.save
  end
```

The failing scenario is like:

```
  Scenario: Student logs in for the first time
    Given I am a valid Student
```

And the failing steps:

```
Before do
  include Authlogic::TestCase
  activate_authlogic
end

def valid_person
    @current_person = Factory.create(:valid_person, :person_profile => new_person_profile('Kelly','Hope'))
end  

Given /^I am a valid Student$/ do
  valid_student
end
```

Thank you 
Adam

Comment: Please show us your failing Cucumber scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I'm going to suggest that the after_create callback is unnecessary. You've already defined `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the `Person` model -- if the objective is to create a `Person` and an associated `PersonProfile` in one step, you should be able to do (eg.):

```
params = { :person => { :name => "John Smith",  
 :person_profile_attributes => { :some_profile_attribute => "some_value" }}}
@person = Person.create!(params[:person])
```