# ActiveRecord changing position on memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, activerecord

I have a rather odd situation here.

My `OrdersController` has an `edit` method and at some point I have the following statement:

```
order_item.item = item
```

As you can guess, `order_item.item` expects a reference to an `Item` object, which is exactly what `item` is. Here comes the mistery. The first time I send a request to `orders/{some_order_id}/edit`, I receive the expected response. But if I send a new request (even if I just press F5) the application crashes and I receive the following error message:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in OrdersController#edit

Item(#177601092) expected, got Item(#67520280)
```

What have I discovered so far? I have put an `puts "#{Item.object_id}"` just before the `order_item.item = item` and found out that `Item.object_id` changes from a request to another, which means that the `Item` ActiveRecord is changing its position on memory. (For instance, in the above example, during the first request `Item.object_id` is `67520280`, while in the second it changes to `177601092`.)

My question is: What can be causing the `Item` ActiveRecord to change its position on memory?

Useful info: I'm using rails 3.0.20

Update:
I found out that this change of ID is pretty common. But I still can't figure out why the expectation doesn't change as the `Item.object_id` does.

Comment: Can you show whole action code (+before filters if any)?

Comment: It doesn't have any filter, @MichaelSzyndel.

Comment: And the rest of action code?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot share it, @MichaelSzyndel. :/

Comment: Found a solution, @MichaelSzyndel. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that I am not using Factory Girl, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145165/associationtypemismatch-and-factorygirl/5841399#5841399) and [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/factory_girl/2qJFVtkMMfw) helped me a lot.

tl;dr

The problem was solved when I set `cached_classes` to `true` in my environment.